# A histogram using a DICOM file?

Tags: matlab, dicom

I'm trying to make a histogram out of a DICOM file, but for the life of me I still can't figure out why I'm getting a negative value for an index. I've transposed the image but the index is still negative and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. The values should be all correct for the file size, header, depth, and width, and the program I'm trying to process this in is MATLAB.

```
clear 
fpointer=fopen('PIG_CT','r');
fseek(fpointer,980,'bof');
img=zeros(512,512);
img(:)=fread(fpointer,(512*512),'short');
img=transpose(img);
depth = 16;
width = depth/64;
fmax = max(max(img));
fmin = min(min(img));
hist64 = zeros(64,1);
for i = 1:512
  for j = 1:512
    rho = img(i,j);
    b64 = floor(rho/width+1)+1;
    hist64(b64,1)= hist64(b64,1)+1;
end
end
bar(hist64)
```

ERROR: Attempted to access hist64(-4094,1); index must be a positive integer or logical.

The equation that I am also using with this is:

Bin Width = (Image Depth)/(# of Bins)

Comment: Is `img` a `short`? Looks like when you add 1 when you assign `b64` you get an overflow. Try converting to `double`.

Comment: Still no luck - I now get the error "In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same." I am pretty sure I am calling the max/min functions wrong, I know I need to use them, I just don't know where.

Comment: What's the value of `b64` when it fails?

Comment: The value is -4094, which can't be right because it's a negative number. I thought that the transpose function would fix that, but it doesn't look like it has done anything.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you are trying to achieve? It looks like the image value (`rho`) gets multiplied by 4 to yield `b64`. So if `fmax > 16`, the index will be larger than the size of `hist64`, which leads me to believe there is a structural error in the algorithm.
Also, try `img(:)=double(fread(fpointer,(512*512),'short'));`

Comment: I'm trying to generate a histogram from the data stored in a dicom file, and the size of the file is 512x512, the dataset is 12 bits, the header is 980 bytes (e.g. fseek), and the depth is 16 bytes. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error. I also am using the equation I just edited to put in the question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's not an overflow. Suppose `img(i,j) == -1024`, then you'll get this error. Try reading the image as unsigned short (`ushort `).
Your histogram algorithm is still flawed if `img` contains values > 16.

Comment: Still gives me the same error - I don't think that the data type is the problem. I'm pretty sure that I have to use fmax and fmin somewhere, I just don't know where.

Comment: Something like `img = (img - fmin) / (fmax - fmin);`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for avoiding hist (or histc) and dicomread in matlab?

Comment: **`depth`** should be `4096` for a 12-bit image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MATLAB, but it looks like you're just reading the file from a specific seek point. Using a DICOM toolkit would ensure you get the actual pixel data attribute entry hand handle any encoding you're likely to run into.

Also, check if your DICOM reader is applying the rescale slope and intercept. Typically this will convert a CT image to Hounsfield units, which have negative values (though -4094 seems a bit much given air is -1000).